# How to use filter_var to return true or false if value matches the filter?

Tags: php, filter-var

Is there a way to use filter_var in php to return true if values matches the correct filter and false otherwise?

What I am trying to get is:

```
filter_var('email@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) => true
filter_var('http://google.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) => true
filter_var('http://google', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) => false
filter_var('test', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) => false
```

Thank you!

Comment: please visit the following link it will ans your question:http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Filtering-Data-with-PHP.html#8

Comment: Why would the third one return `false`?

Comment: @PeeHaa because thats not an email

Comment: It's an URL @RashidShafique ...

Comment: Looks like you can't have a direct boolean value.

Answer (score 2):

How about wrapping this function around a function that meets your requirement?
For example:

```
function my_filter_var($a, $b) {
    if(filter_var($a, $b)===false){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

However I won't suggest using this because it is an unnecessary call to a function when you can achieve what you desire without actually calling a function (because calling a function is expensive).
Posted this function just because you wanted output in a certain format.

So this function will work as follow:

```
my_filter_var('email@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) => true
my_filter_var('http://google.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) => true
my_filter_var('http://google', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) => false
my_filter_var('test', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) => false
```

You should rather use what I did inside function, instead of creating a function.

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted, this is possibly the closest to what OP was asking for ...

Comment: "(because calling a function is expensive)" You reeeeeeeeeeally don't have to worry about this, because any difference wouldn't be noticeable.

Comment: Negligible but it does make a difference. I wouldn't recommend anyone to create a new function just because one wanted to avoid writing an if statement!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it either, but that statement saying it does make a difference is "wrong".

Comment: It will make a difference when someone start making such functions for several such things and they are used extensively. My point is to not make it a habit in someone's programming style.

Comment: Obligatory http://www.quickmeme.com/img/d2/d26f0ee993134aaee20c8e67eff93aa6d089cd82f912a68316a38de4a3b7c551.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I would use something simple like this:

```
(bool) filter_var('email@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

which will always result in a boolean: https://3v4l.org/BvAdE

Also note that you said you expect your third example to return `false` however `http://google` is a perfectly valid URL.

Answer (score 0):

It returns the filtered value if valid and false otherwise, so this should work.

```
$valid_email = filter_var('email@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? true : false;
```

Same for url

```
$valid_url = filter_var('http://google.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> Returns the filtered data, or FALSE if the filter fails.

Therefore:

```
if( filter_var('email@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === FALSE ){
  // Invalid
}else {
  // Valid
}
```

Is valid code. Check out [the documentation for filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) for further info.

Comment: I need a boolean value as a direct result, without an if. I thought I was missing something, but this is the only option.

Comment: Then use something in the form: `$valid = (filter_var('email@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== FALSE)`